# Might being used for a past action

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, modal-verbs

Is the sentence bellow possible? Why is *might* being used here although the sentence is in the past? Shouldn't it be "Might have" instead?

> You said hey. I said hello.

> A: "I gotta know, do you feel this way?"

> You said: "yeah I do, but I was scared of what you **might** say"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Might* is past tense (although sometimes used in the present tense as well).

- I am scared of what you may say.
- I was scared of what you might say.